# Center floating div horizontally without absolute position

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering a div (logo) on the page. I've tried a few things but they don't seem to be working.

I was able to center the logo on the page by setting text-align to center for the container and using absolute position to grid_4 (right: 0;). However when minimizing the browser, the 2 divs overlap.

```
    <!-- header -->
<header>

  <div class="container">


    <div class="grid_8 center-touch full-width wow fadeInDown animated">

      <a href="/">                       
        {% if settings.use_logo %}
        <img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name | escape }}" class="logo" />
        {% else %}
        <h1 class="logo">{{ shop.name | escape }}</h1>
        {% endif %}
      </a>

    </div>

    <div class="grid_4 right m-t-35 m-b-10 hide-touch wow fadeInDown animated">

      <div class="cart">

        <span class="total">{{ cart.total_price | money_with_currency }}</span>

      </div>

      <a href="/cart" class="cart-btn" title="Your cart"><span class="count">{{ cart.item_count }}</span></a> 

    </div>

  </div>




  <div class="clear"></div>

  {% include 'navigation' %}

</header>
```

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Comment: Sorry. I just added the code. Thanks

Comment: does it have to be floated? I would set it to display inline-block and set its parent's text-align to center. No need to keep it floated if you want it centered

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Hi it doesn't have to be floated. Can you she me an example?

Comment: @crocparkisland theres this http://jsfiddle.net/u0h1p1nv/ see if that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center your logo adding :

```
.container > .grid_8 > a {
    float: right;
}
```

and to fix your responsive

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container > .grid_8 > a {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

It should work I have already tested it.

**Note:** Try to add some id or classe to your logo container and instead of selecting `.container > .grid_8 > a` use your `#your_logo_id`

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect. It took me the past couple of days to try to get this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To the anchor tag, give css properties as follows:

```
.grid_8 > a {
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;}
.grid_8 > h1 {
display: inline-block;}
```

This works like a charm.